# Localhost and CORS with Auth0 not allowing me to login

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm making a React app and trying to use Auth0 to authenticate. After trying to log in, it returns this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-domain.auth0.com/usernamepassword/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I thought it would be related to this: [CORS problems with Auth0 and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495297/cors-problems-with-auth0-and-react) but I have both `http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000/login` in the 'Allowed Origins (CORS)' spot in Auth0's settings (and yes I'm using the correct client ID as well).

I tried putting `http://localhost:3000/, http://localhost:3000/login` in the 'Allowed Callback URL's (don't know exactly what that does) but that didn't work either.

When I use the social connection (Google) it allowed me to login after putting `http://localhost:3000/login` in the Allowed Callback URL's.

But it still won't work for just a new user logging in.

Any help?

If it makes a difference:

- Auth0 Logs show for the social login but there are no logs at all for when I connect otherwise
- I think related to this is that I also get this every time I load the page:

  > There was an error fetching the SSO data. This could simply mean that there was a problem with the network. But, if a "Origin" error has been logged before this warning, please add "http://localhost:3000" to the "Allowed Origins (CORS)" list in the Auth0 dashboard: ...(link to my dash)
- I get a 404 from the gravatar website
- Also I get these errors (may not be related):

`Refused to set unsafe header "accept-encoding"`

`Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"`

Comment: Do you have a copy of your app available on a git repo etc?  I can take a look if you like - using my own tenant to verify the issue is your code base or a misconfiguration from Dashboard.  If you try enabling a Social connection (google etc - you can just use the Auth0 Dev keys) for the same Client does logging in with Social provider work for you?  Or same error..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with answers to that + the code is at [EMR Test Web Page](https://github.com/canada11/ExampleEMRWebPage) all the code is in the client folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something was wrong with the client in Auth0. I don't know what it was but I built an Angular4 app and connected to the same client in Auth0 and got the same errors. I then tried deleting the client in Auth0 and making a new one and now it works. I have no idea what was causing the error, but creating a new client and connecting to that one fixed the issue.