# Getting a CORS error when trying to authenticate user with Auth0

Tags: cors, next.js, auth0

## Edit

[Reproducible repo here](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-auth0)

I'm aware that these creds should never hit the internet, but I'm getting desperate here + I'll delete the client/tenant afterward anyway.

---

I have a route set up:

```
router.get('/login', cors, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('Entered')
        await auth0.handleLogin(req, res)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).end()
})
```

The line `Entered` gets printed, however I keep catching a cors error,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://dev-..' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login')
 from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've been pulling my hair out for several h̶o̶u̶r̶s̶ days now.

I'm not sure why the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` is showing up, as I've added the `cors` package to my custom Express server.

What am I doing wrong here? I've followed [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial/) which uses `passport-auth0` and I've followed these [docs](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) (which is the package used in the repository above) as well -- both approaches show the same error.

In my Auth0 dashboard, I've set up my allowed origins as follows (ie, I followed [this](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/set-up-cors):
[image: img1]

I have no idea where to go from here. If I manually paste the URL from the console error, `https://dev-..` then it takes me to the auth page and successfully redirects me to `localhost:3000/`.

[Here](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-auth0/blob/master/utils/initAuth0.ts) are my init Auth0 settings.

I've seen some similar questions online, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263386/2891356), but creating a new client hasn't helped me, and the other answers haven't either. I've crawled through nearly every relevant question on the Auth0 Community forum.

I've also cloned and ran the example [here](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/master/examples/basic-example), and it worked with their pages API. I'm starting to think, that I can't use this `nextjs-auth0` package with a custom server.

Comment: Because you’re redirecting a frontend request to that `https://dev-..` URL, and the response comes back from that URL, it’s not sufficient just to CORS-enable your `http://localhost:3000` server only. Instead, that `https://dev-..` server must be CORS-enabled also. And apparently it’s not. And if it’s an OAuth endpoint, it’s normal and expected that it’s not CORS-enabled. That’s because OAuth endpoints aren’t meant to receive scripted ajax requests via XHR or Fetch or whatever. Instead, the user’s meant to be navigated to the endpoint and then navigated back. You can’t navigate users with XHR.

Comment: I dug deeper and I see what you're saying. However, as I've shown in the question, I've set up `http://localhost:3000` as Allowed Origins (CORS) and Allowed Web Origins. Like I said, I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: I haven't tried this approach with Next.js before but have auth0 working with a couple of other JS frameworks without too many issues. 

I would guess there's an issue with how the redirect is being made to the auth0 login page. Basically it shouldn't be making a CORS request on login, it should be sending the whole browser off to the auth0 domain to login then sending the client back with the tokens. 
I've cloned your repo, it's strange that the handleLogin method doesn't return a 302 to the browser.

Comment: The thing that is really bothering me is the fact that I've taken a look at their [examples](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/master/examples), cloned them myself, and got them to work with ease. The only difference that I could note, is the fact that I'm using a custom server to handle the login, whereas they are using their pages API. [This](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/master/examples/sample-api) example is also strange, as it uses a custom server as well, but it doesn't do any authentication, just authorization, if I'm seeing it right. No clue where to go from here.

Comment: I think the issue is going to be somewhere in "custom server to handle the login". The 2nd example is the resource server - so that's a backend that is using the access token to allow authn/z to the APIs. The problem is how you acquire the token - your UI needs to do a 302 redirect to the auth0 login page (not using XHR), allow auth0 to take care of all the login process (can include registration, 2fa etc) then it will redirect back to your app with a token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using browser redirect, you are sending asynchronous request which is the reason why Auth0 is not working for you and is giving you CORS error.

Update your **Home** view with following code and it will fix your issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <a href='/login'>login</a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

P.S: I tried this changes with forking your repo and it is working as expected for me, let me know if you still see the issue.

Comment: This works. Just want to confirm, whichever route I have on the backend, in this case `/login`, is accessible with a simple `<a> tag? Is this a nextjs thing? I dont recall ReactJS behaving the same way with an Express backend.

Comment: Not really, it is not nextjs thing but it is part of OAuth implicit grant spec, I guess. As a rule of thumb all request which can result in response with redirection (location header in the response) should happen directly via browser. Even you can keep your handler as before but instead of calling endpoint asynchronous, you would have to call window.location=newUrl.

Comment: There are definitely ways to get around this issue, but this is the simplest approach.

Comment: You can follow this thread on axios, which might have answer you are looking for if not currently may be sometime in future: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932