# Passport.js, Auth0 CORS error

Tags: angular, express, passport.js, auth0

I'm trying to set up a single page app using Angular 5 and Express, that authenticates with Passport.js and Auth0. I keep getting this error when I try to log in:

> Failed to load
>   https://example.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback&client_id=example:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

According to [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495962/1253298), it looks like maybe the callback is wrong, but I don't understand why there would be a CORS error for having an incorrect callback, or if that is even relevant for a single-page app.

Currently in dev, I'm running my Angular app on localhost:8080, and my server on localhost:3000. Obviously, I'll need to run them both on the same server at some point, but maybe this is causing problems?...

I've tried several things in the Auth0 settings page, but not sure what to enter in the fields for Callback URLs, Allowed Web Origins, and Allowed Origins (CORS).

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
var db = require('./db');

const CLIENT_ORIGIN = 'http://localhost:8080';
const SERVER_PORT_NUMBER = 3000;

passport.use(new Auth0Strategy({
    domain: 'example.auth0.com',
    clientID: 'example',
    clientSecret: '7Jk3OdKOgWEKta8UFSrAU6lD04kPizC9aT0x6M8FlY1R7QTtJk_vqutYdfk3gUul',
    callbackURL: '/callback',
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, cb) {
    return done(null, profile);
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(email, cb) {
  db.users.findByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});

var app = express();

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', CLIENT_ORIGIN);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();

});

// Configure view engine to render EJS templates.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(require('morgan')('combined'));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/',
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });

app.get('/user/login',
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
  });

app.get('/callback',
  function(req, res) {
      console.log('test);
  });

app.post('/user/login',
  passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }),

  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/user/logout',
  function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/user/profile',
  require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });


app.listen(SERVER_PORT_NUMBER);
```

**UPDATE:** I also tried npm cors as suggested:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With,content-type',
  credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

This didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The url in the error show that you are calling a route '/callback' but I do not see a such route in your code.

As a side note, you could give a try to the well known [cors npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Thanks. As far as your first suggestion, I've added the `/callback` route, and I still get the same error.

Comment: As mentioned in the update, I also tried cors npm package. Still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a different error message or is it still the same in the both cases?

Comment: Unfortunately for this question, we’ve moved on to another solution.